# php/regex - remove single tags

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, preg-replace

I would like to export some single tags that doesn't make sense in my text (exported from MS Word), such as:

```
<b stuff /> and <i stuff />.
```

I've tried the following regex:

```
/<b(.*?)\/>/i
```

But it doesn't work when I have something like:

```
<i>My text</i> some other text<i class="stuff" /> my final text.
```

Instead of getting only the single tag, it gets everything. How could I fix this, please? The final result must be:

```
<i>My text</i> some other text my final text.
```

UPDATE:
aelor's answer was the closest to the one I needed. In the end, I mixed both aelor and Mikhail's answer to get this:

```
/(\s?)<[ib][^>]+\/>(\s?)/
```

Thanks!

Comment: `/<(b|i) (.*?)\/>/i` matches both the `b` and the `i`. I'd add a space after to prevent removal of other tags.

Comment: `.*?` is lazy and will match as little as possible. It's also "match any character zero to infinity times" hence your regex matches include the first tag as well. `.+?` is lazy "1 to infinity" search. `[^>]+` meaning "any character that isn't `>` matched 1 to infinity times" is much more useful and much better performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search `<[^>]+\/>`

and replace with nothing.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/xV4xX8